# When did Stradivarius become "Stradivarius!"

Tags: history, string-instruments, lutherie

Instruments built by the Stradivarius family are popularly thought of amongst the pantheon of "greatest ever".<sup>1</sup> But have they always been considered this way? Were they held in similarly high regard in their day and continuously up to the present? Were they just ordinary violins until some "great master" musician declared them the best, and the declaration became self-fulfilling?

What is the origin and history of the popular fame of the Stradivarius?

---

<sup>1</sup> I make no claim one way or another about the actual quality of the instruments; I'm interested in the history or their popular reputation, regardless individual opinion of them.

Comment: I feel like there are two "levels" to the question. Were they celebrated, elite collector's pieces even in their own time? Sure. But the second question is about how "household names," those names that represent their categories to the exclusion of others, get to be that way. Itzhak Perlman, Yo-Yo Ma, Julliard, Steinway... These are names that everyone is familiar with, even if unfamiliar with, say, Joshua Bell, Jacqueline du Pré, Curtis Institute, and Bösendorfer. How did Stradivarius come to eclipse in this way Amati, Stainer, Guerneri, et al? That sounds like a fascinating mystery story.

Comment: Almost the same question could be posed regarding the Stratocaster.

Comment: I consider this as question weakly related to music, and completely explained by the psychological urge to rank (raising from a cognitional overload if  the numerous relevant facets would have to be prioritzed and evaluated separately). While the most striking examples **are** instruments (grand piano -> Steinway, bassoon -> Heckel), a similar list may be created e.g. for cars easily.

Comment: @guidot The phenomenon holds for other entities, too; people (when did Shakespeare become *Shakespeare*) or institutions (cf Juilliard vs every other music school). But of course you can't valuate or hoard people or institutions (well, I mean you *can*, but not in the same ways); Strads stand at a perfect-storm convergence of economics, art object, and sociology as mediated through the commodity of classical music (and indeed the keystone role the violin played in that history).

Comment: @guidot In other words, I'm defending it as a music-history question because, although human creatures always have loved to fetishize and meme-ify their favorite cultural artifacts, the reception history of the Strad stands as a model of the reception history of classical music.

Comment: @Tim I think '59 Les Paul Standard would be closer equivalent. Stratocaster was intended to be mass produced right from beginning.

Comment: @ojs Lol, you could argue that so were Stradivaris (over 1,000 instruments over ca 50 years, running a family workshop under his own name).

Comment: @guidot Your comment addresses the matter of why we rank things, but it doesn't address why Strads came to be placed at the top of the ranking. Are you suggesting that a large population of people all arbitrarily and independently picked the same instrument to rank at the top?

Comment: @AndyBonner 20 instruments per year sounds like small boutique builder to me. For comparison, 1000 Stratocasters are currently made in a week.

Comment: Isn't the thing that really makes a "Stradivarius" their crazy sale prices and mystique in the general public? Not blind listening tests. I knew a cellist who was more impressed with his Guadagnini instrument. Maybe sale prices are an indicator to consider.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis That's exactly the question: when and how did the mystique come into being?

Comment: I wish I could give you dates, but I don't know the topic. I'm just suggesting a history of sale prices could be a way to try to make "mystique" a bit more objective.

Comment: Say *Stradivarius* to a violinist and they'll imagine a *violin*, but say it to a brass player and they'll imagine a trumpet or trombone maybe...

Answer (score 1):

They were famous from the first, as were some other Cremona violin makers. Later on, the Strads were rebuilt (as were other marks) to 19th century standards; the rebuilds worked better on the Strads. There is a (possibly apocryphal) story about Cremona factory signs. Supposedly Amati, Guarneri, and Stradivarius each had a factory on the same block in Cremona.

Amati had a sign on their factory: "Best Violins in Italy."
Guarneri had a sign on their factory: "Best Violins in the World."
Stradivarius had a sign on their factory: "Best Violins on the Block."

Comment: Alright, which one of those companies made the best violins...? (Yes, I know all of those slogans have a chance of spouting hyperbole on their own and mutually contradict each other.)

Comment: Ha... Reminds me of John being asked whether Ringo was the best drummer in the world and responding, "He's not even the best drummer in the Beatles!"

Comment: @Dekkadeci Although I haven't researched enough yet, the anecdote smacks of myth. But as to "which is best," I could slyly say that that would be introducing a subjective question. But that's kind of Aaron's point: if he was one among equals in his day, and if even today some players might say (with perhaps a hint of sour grapes) "I prefer a Guarneri"... Then why *is* a Strad a *Strad*, and (maybe the more fascinating) *when* did it become one? (Let the record show I intend to post an answer, but need more research.)

Answer (score 0):

I think for the type of performer that these violins are a possibility it is not just the quality of the workmanship, but the oldness of the wood. There is no way to fake old wood. As a violin vibrates, the sound goes into the fibers of the wood and trough many years of playing the tone improves. I do believe that these violins would be pretty temperamental. They may also have problem with intonation and staying in tune, but all these minor inconveniences may be worthwhile for the warm tone that simply cannot be had by a violin compromising of any younger wood.

Comment: I'm not asking why they're considered good instruments. I'm asking for the history of when and how they became known as "the best."

Comment: They started being considered the best when people realised the older the wood the better the sounds the violin makes.

Comment: That would make exactly the answer I'm looking for as long as you can include some specifics of when and how that realization came about, along with some sources.

Comment: Also probably a fact that there full tonal capabilities were not fully realised in the days of gut strings. The strads were probably violins with the oldest wood and an acceptable level of craftsmanship. The craftsmanship improved over the years, but that level of old wood could never be attained again.

Comment: _sound goes into the fibers of the wood and trough many years of playing the tone improves_ [citation needed]